# SQL Statement to insert a count by email and date

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have an issue which I'm trying to solve.
We contact customers a number of times during an application. We don't count how many times we call them. I want to get an SQL statement which this by date.

Attached is an image of how the column should appear, with the inserted column in yellow.
Would be amazing to see this statement!

thanks
Matt

[image]

Comment: Where is the call information stored? Are your call records stored inside of a separate DE?

Comment: Two images provided seem to be identical. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gortonington all records are in the same table

Comment: @Ranga, sorry i put in the image twice accidently!

Comment: You should be able to do something like: `select count(id), Email From ObjectName Group By Email`

Comment: @Ranga - Please put that as an answer - Also make sure to note it should target the DE from the image and use Action as UPDATE. This will add in the count into the call field in the DE.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

`[select count(Id), Email From ObjectName Group By Email]`